# How to replace text in js without the spaces affecting the process

Tags: javascript, c#, php, regex

I have this code in PHP that will replace some words with other ones:

```
$Data1 = array("/Hello\s+there/i", "/I\s*m\s+Good!/i");
$Data2 = array("bye", "How are you?");
$data = preg_replace($Data1, $Data2, $data);
```

the code in PHP gets the value ($data) and replaces all words that are in $Data1 array with the words in the words in the array $Data2 without caring for spaces between words (\s+, \s*).
like this (`TheOriginalText ==> TheNewText`):

```
Hello there!, something else     ==> bye!, something else
Hello   there !, something else  ==> bye!, something else
Hello~there !, something else    ==> Hello~there !, something else
```

For js, using the `str.replace` will do this(`TheOriginalText ==> TheNewText`):

```
Hello there!, something else     ==> bye!, something else
Hello   there !, something else  ==> Hello   there !, something else
Hello~there !, something else    ==> Hello~there !, something else
```

but I don't want the spaces to affect the replacing process.
I've tried to use this code in js, but it didn't work:

```
function Code(data){
  var Code1 = [/Print/i, /Prin_/i, /New~Line/i];
  var JSCode = ["document.write", "document.write('<br>\n');document.write", "document.write('<br>\n');"];
  return data = str.replace(Code1, JSCode);
}
```

Is there any other code that will do the same thing using arrays in js and c# (most likely I need it in js more than c#)

Comment: did my answwer help you?

Comment: no, this is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) for JavaScript:

```
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
var res = str.replace(/blue/gi, "red");
```

The result is:

```
Mr red has a red house and a red car.
```

Comment: Is there any way to replace text without the spaces affecting the process

Comment: @EnderAdel please explain better your need

Comment: reload your page